# Show form and fetch data on background meanwhile

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, forms, backgroundworker

I'm working on a `winforms` application that works with database a lot, and 90% of my forms need to load some initial data from database on `Form_Load`.

I've been told to use threading to show the form, and then go and fetch data and fill the form with data, otherwise the customer can't see the form until the postman goes to the db and comes back with data :)

I've done some simple tasks with threads before, but this case is a bit confusing to me. I have a mainForm which is the `MdiParent` and other forms are `MdiChild` like below:

```
ChildForm child = new ChildForm { MdiParent = Program.mainForm };
```

and my mainForm (the `MdiParent` is static in `Program.cs`)

I don't know whether I should use `Thread`? `BackgroundWorker`? Other solutions?

I would be way more than happy if your kind replies could help me through this case and empower my incomplete knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a BackgroundWorker is the easiest way to go.  It handles the threading issues, catching exceptions and runs the work completion callback on the UI Thread.

If you are using C# 4.5, then await/asych is also a good approach.

Comment: So I should use a BackgroundWorker in each form's load event and give it a method (containing the db works) and run it, am I right?